# Dividing by Items in CSV File

Tags: python

Here is an image of my CSV file:

[image: Image of my CSV file]

```
import csv

f = open("datatest.csv")
reader = csv.reader(f)

dataListed = [row for row in reader]

rc = csv.writer(f)  

column1 = []
for row in dataListed:
    column1.append(row[0])
    
column2 = []
for row in dataListed:
    column2.append(row[1])

divide = []
for row in dataListed:
    divide = row[1] / row[2]

print(divide)
```

Why does the "divide" list not work? Everything else works as it should, I always just get an error for that that says something about strings, when I try to change the row[1 and 2] as a float, it breaks too! Help is greatly appreciated,
I am a pure beginner. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot issues in your code.

Firstly, your `dataListed`  looks like this

```
[['lis1', 'lis2'], ['1', '2'], ['2', '7'], ['3', '9'], ['10', '10']]
```

You are trying to divide 2 string items like so.

```
divide = 'lis1'/'lis2' - TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'
```

so you need to remove 1st elemnt from list.

Secondly,

```
divide = row[1] / row[2]
```

your list has only 2 elemnts list index starts with `0` so it should be

```
 divide = row[0] / row[1]
```

### complete code after code correction

```
import csv

f = open(r"Tomas.csv")
reader = csv.reader(f)

dataListed = [row for row in reader]

rc = csv.writer(f)  

column1 = []
for row in dataListed:
    column1.append(row[0])
    
column2 = []
for row in dataListed:
    column2.append(row[1])

dataListed.pop(0)

divide = []
for row in dataListed:
    
    re = int(row[1]) / int(row[0])
    divide.append(re)
    

print(divide)
```

Gives #

```
[2.0, 3.5, 3.0, 1.0]
```

have you considered using other libraries Thomas?
using pandas is very very easy -  [pandas](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/)

say your csv looks like this

```
   lis1  lis2
0     1     2
1     2     7
2     3     9
3    10    10
```

Then

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r"Thomas.csv")
df['new_list_after_Divison'] = (df['lis2']/df['lis1'])
print(df)
```

Gives #

```
    lis1   lis2              new_list_after_Divison
0     1     2                       2.0
1     2     7                       3.5
2     3     9                       3.0
3    10    10                       1.0
```

Comment: You could improve the code further by iterating through the file directly instead of doing 4 times

Comment: Yeah agree @PaulH...After seeing OP approch thought OP was pretty new to python & don't want to change many things in his code...just made some corrections explaing what are the issues with this code & how to solve them...I've also added alternate easy approch to solve this...you want me to optimize code?